# Cocos2D 'fake' 3D projection on sprites. How to update Box2D bodies AND the debug draw to match.

Tags: ios, ios6, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I am using Cocos2D with the following settings:
`[director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];` in the appDelegate class
`kmGLRotatef(-47, 1.0, 0, 0);` in my layer's draw method
This ensures that my objects are presented in a simulated 3D environment.

I've added Box2D for collision detection. I've setup the bodies. When I enable the debug drawing, then the bodies are arranged on the whole screen and the sprites are arranged in a perspective.

How can I add the same perspective for the bodies too?

Comment: are the debug bodies drawn using opengl?

Comment: I am using the GLES-Render class from the cocos2d sample project.

Comment: I believe your problem is that they are drawn in different space, you may need to set the openGL matrix manually. in order to transform your debug view into 3d. Are you just drawing outlines?

Comment: Yes, I am drawing just outlines.

Comment: How can I set this matrix? Can you give me some clues please?

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to use gl projection matrices and rotate functions as the debug drawing lives outside cocos (for good reason).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34585/discussion-between-infinite-possibilities-and-mitchell-currie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advice given is to find a bounding box from the fake 3d transformation in cocos2d of the sprite. Then use this bounding box for both the body's debug drawing and also to determine the new (or transformed) body for box2d.